# De-cache user browser content after asp.net intranet site deployment?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, caching, header

Is there a standard practice for forcing users to refresh their cached browser content after intranet deployments?  They tend to have conflicting JavaScript cached in their browsers, and must hit F5 to get rid of JavaScript errors in IE 8.0.  Per management, we deploy during business hours.

The need is to invalidate/expire each user's cache a single time on first hit to the site, then let the user resume caching normally.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't force a browser to flush its cache, but you *can* force it to reload something by adding a dummy query part to the URL:

```
<script src='js/stuff_that_changes.js?dummy=001'></script>
```

When you want to force a new version, you update the URL references to "002", "003", etc.  Exactly how you do that depends a lot on your server-side technology.

Comment: Interesting.  I'll try that.

Thanks!

Comment: As an additional note, I have done this by appending the last changed timestamp (in ticks) of the js file to the querystring. This way, as soon as the file is changed, the querystring will update (you don't have to do anything).

Comment: Mark, what's the cleanest way to do this?  Post-build steps work for everything except dynamically-rendered references.  What do you think about a BeginRequest handler, an HttpModule, or basically manipulating the markup (e.g., looping through header and page controls and changing references) on an OnPreRenderComplete handler?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention this is for an intranet application, one approach you can take to help in this type of situation is to alter the expiration of all items the browser might cache from the intranet site by setting the HTTP Response Headers for all intranet site content. If all users on the intranet are expected to have relatively speedy connections (i.e. are they all on the office LAN), then you can force the expiration to a very low value and it should not too problematic unless you have a very large number of users or have users with slower connections. This way all items in the user's browser cache are exiring relatively quickly and you shouldn't have much of an issue with rolling out frequent changes to the site. The following article is a howto on configuring this in IIS7.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: We've tried that, but even with static caching set to less than a minute or even disabled, we have had a lot of problems with IE 8 holding not checking for the new content and producing JS errors.  Hence, we're considering tagging JS/CSS references with a version number in order to force new content to be loaded.